# AWS ssm send-command : modify timeout in CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssm

I'm using AWS SSM to compute a long script on an ec2 instance.

I would like to configure the execution timeout (execution time, not launch time) and I don't find how to do this on the official documentation (opposing informations or not working).

I'm using only the CLI interface.

Answer (score 2):

This value is a document property that can be passed with `--parameters` option using `executionTimeout` key. You can use `aws ssm describe-documents` to find this and other document specific parameters.

```
aws ssm describe-document --name "AWS-RunShellScript"

{
    "Document": {
        "Hash": "99749de5e62f71e5ebe9a55c2321e2c394796afe7208cff048696541e6f6771e",
        "HashType": "Sha256",
        "Name": "AWS-RunShellScript",
        "Owner": "Amazon",
        "CreatedDate": "2017-08-21T22:25:02.029000+02:00",
        "Status": "Active",
        "DocumentVersion": "1",
        "Description": "Run a shell script or specify the commands to run.",
        "Parameters": [
            {
                "Name": "commands",
                "Type": "StringList",
                "Description": "(Required) Specify a shell script or a command to run."
            },
            {
                "Name": "workingDirectory",
                "Type": "String",
                "Description": "(Optional) The path to the working directory on your instance.",
                "DefaultValue": ""
            },
            {
                "Name": "executionTimeout",
                "Type": "String",
                "Description": "(Optional) The time in seconds for a command to complete before it is considered to have failed. Default is 3600 (1 hour). Maximum is 172800 (48 hours).",
                "DefaultValue": "3600"
            }
        ],
        "PlatformTypes": [
            "Linux",
            "MacOS"
        ],
        "DocumentType": "Command",
        "SchemaVersion": "1.2",
        "LatestVersion": "1",
        "DefaultVersion": "1",
        "DocumentFormat": "JSON",
        "Tags": []
    }
}
```